# XAMPP how to increase upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, file-upload, xampp

I have installed XAMPP on Win 10. Actually I am trying to import sql file which has 11MB via PhpMyAdmin which throws me an error - Propably too big file... Before XAMPP I had my own instlation of Apache/PHP with .htaccess in the document root which solved this problem like a charm. Its content is

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

I have it there also for xampp, but I m not able to upload this file. Smaller files works fine. Also I change php.ini from phpinfo(). It makes me crazy... What a dark magic is behind the xampp?

Comment: Have you tried restarting apache in xampp after changing the php.ini file? What is the value of AllowOverride in httpd.conf/apache.conf?

Comment: In httpd,conf is AllowOverride none Do you think this is the .htaccess ignore problem?

Comment: I am sorry there are few AlloweOverride directives 1. <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs"> AllowOverride All</Directory> 2. <Directory />
   AllowOverride none </Directory> 3. <Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All </Directory>

Comment: AllowOverride must be set to All for .htaccess files to work. If your DocumentRoot is C:/xampp/htdocs then you should be fine and allowed to use .htaccess files.

Comment: Yes everything looks ok but still the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you have to find right path of your php.ini. First checkout path of php.ini by simple create php file with:

```
phpinfo();
```

Then find line with php.ini file and look on path, then edit this php.ini file with values:

max_uploaded_filesize

When you will update it don't forget to restart xamp web server.

Comment: I have a right php.ini file. I write it in the last paragraph. It looks like max_uploaded_filesize directive is not enough. Now I have changed also post_max_size directive and it works. But this should handle my .htaccess file. I would like to know why php ignore .htaccess directives.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved my problem concerning this issue:
1) Open Xampp control panel.
2) Click on the "config" button behind apache:
   A drop down will appear with several options:
3) Choose the php.ini file
4) Open it using notepad and look for this line:
  " upload_max_filesize=2M " Change the value 2M to a value like 64M.
5) Save the file.
6) Restart Apache.
You are good to go!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using XAMPP on Win10. I've updated `C:\xampp\php\phi.ini` and changed 2M to 200M. WordPress now reports that the limit has increased to 8M. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Paul

Comment: Found it. It is also necessary to set post_max_size=200M

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this error and did all the solutions provided. However, still having the same error until I noticed that I have 2 versions of php (xampp and globally installed) installed and I was editing incorrect php.ini file.

Make sure to edit correct the correct file by command `php --ini` in your cli.

P.S I'm using Laravel